How can Sanhedrin abolish "whole body of Halachah" from the Torah?
The Mishna in Horayos (1.3) describes a possibility of the Sanhedrin annulling a "whole body of Halachah" from the Torah, such idolatry or Shabbos, and concludes that "they are exempt":

הוֹרוּ בֵית דִּין לַעֲקֹר אֶת כָּל הַגּוּף, אָמְרוּ, אֵין נִדָּה בַתּוֹרָה, אֵין שַׁבָּת בַּתּוֹרָה, אֵין עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה בַתּוֹרָה, הֲרֵי אֵלּוּ פְטוּרִין.‏

There are many interpretations of what "exempt" means, but everybody accepts such a possibility.
Given the procedure for appointing rabbis to the Kosher Sanhedrin (and not a coup), in what universe can a Sanhedrin rule fundamental Halachic pillars, such as idolatry or Shabbos, void?

I think this question is a mistake. The mishnayos in Horoyos are talking about errors made by the Sanhedrin, and when we need to bring a פר העלם דבר as a result. In the case it means that they would not have to bring one, wrong though it is. No one says they're allowed to do this.

Are you just asking, Practically speaking this seems very unlikely!

The Ramban (Bamidbar 15:22) says that this would apply in the case that the leaders of the Jewish people decided that the Torah has been abolished, as indeed happened in the past, such as when the elders of Israel came to Ezekiel with the suggestion that their contract with God was broken and that they should start worshiping idols. Or it could apply in the case that the Torah is forgotten, as happened in the wicked kings of Israel and in the time of Ezra, when the people needed to be reminded of the most basic commandments.

והנה זה כפי משמעו הוא קרבן המשומד לכל התורה בשוגג, כגון ההולך ונדבק לאחת מן האומות לעשות כהם ולא ירצה להיות בכלל ישראל כלל. ויהיה כל זה בשוגג, כגון שיהיה ביחיד בתינוק שנשבה לבין הגוים ובקהל, כגון שיחשבו שכבר עבר זמן התורה ולא היתה לדורות עולם. או שיאמרו, כמוזכר בסיפרי (ספרי במדבר ט״ו:מ״א): מפני מה אמר המקום, לא שנעשה ונטול שכר? לא עושין ולא נוטלין. כענין שהיו ישראל אומרים ושואלין את יחזקאל שנאמר: ויבואו אלי אנשים מזקני ישראל וישבו לפני (יחזקאל י״ד:א׳). אמרו לו רבינו יחזקאל הרי עבד שמכרו רבו לא יצא מרשותו וכו׳. או שישכחו את התורה, וכבר אירע לנו כן בעונותינו כי בימי מלכי ישראל הרשעים כגון ירבעם שכחו רוב העם התורה והמצות לגמרי, וכאשר בא בספר עזרא באנשי בית שני.‏

The truth is that your question is about the slightly different case of ruling that one of the commandments (rather than the entire Torah) isn't in force; however, both answers might still apply: the Sanhedrin could reach the conclusion that one part of the Torah is abolished through a process of reasoning, or one part of the Torah could be forgotten.

+1 Thank you. I struggle to imagine a functioning [Kosher] Sanhedrin in Biblical times. In the Second-Temple times, how, do you think, could such a Pharisee Sanhedrin form? I can think of  Sadusee or Essenes, but not Pharisee.

@AlBerko The definition of abolishing a "whole body of halacha" is actually to go against something that even the Sadducees accept (Horayot 4a). So, in this respect, Pharisees and Sadducees would be equal, meaning this would require a level of ignorance that neither Pharisees nor Sadducees ever reached

Exactly, so my question is, how, given the procedure of appointing the judges, could this ignorance happen? Based on the doctrine of uninterruptible Oral tradition passed through the Sanhedrin, of course?

@AlBerko If that happens, the oral tradition through the Sanhedrin would apparently be broken. Of the three cases the Ramban cites, one was a partial "coup" and the other two were a result of the Babylonian exile when the Sanhedrin's existence was in fact interrupted in Israel and the chain of tradition goes through Babylonia
